# Group objects in php with similar course_id

Tags: php

I have a variable `$items` that has following data inside it.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [course_id] => 8
            [doc_id] => 85
            [doc_title] => PDF Notes
            [doc_price] => 243
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [course_id] => 6
            [doc_id] => 73
            [doc_title] => PDF Notes
            [doc_price] => 12
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [course_id] => 6
            [doc_id] => 75
            [doc_title] => Audio Topics
            [doc_price] => 21
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [course_id] => 6
            [doc_id] => 77
            [doc_title] => Video Past Papers
            [doc_price] => 32
        )

)
```

I want to categorize the data. The course_id should become the key and the courses that have similar course_id should be categorized and become the value of that key. Like in the about array, [1], [2] and [3] have same course_id so the for key => 6, an array should be made with sub array that have docs 73, 75 and 77.

```
array => (
    '6' => 'array of docs with course_id 6',
    '8' => 'array of docs with course_id 8',
)
```

**VAR_EXPORT**

```
array (
  0 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'course_id' => '8',
     'doc_id' => '85',
     'doc_title' => 'PDF Notes',
     'doc_price' => '243',
  )),
  1 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'course_id' => '6',
     'doc_id' => '73',
     'doc_title' => 'PDF Notes',
     'doc_price' => '12',
  )),
  2 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'course_id' => '6',
     'doc_id' => '75',
     'doc_title' => 'Audio Topics',
     'doc_price' => '21',
  )),
  3 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'course_id' => '6',
     'doc_id' => '77',
     'doc_title' => 'Video Past Papers',
     'doc_price' => '32',
  )),
)
```

Comment: Can you provide a `var_export($items)` output so we can easily copy and paste the array for our answers.

Comment: added. please see the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
use get_object_vars to convert obj to array.

```
$newarray = array();
foreach ($items as $item)
{
  $newarray[$item->course_id][] = get_object_vars($item); 
}
```

Comment: I dont want to use objects. I want them to be simple array,

Comment: use get_object_vars function to convert obj to array